# Reading a 3-candidate hash tree structure

Tags: data-mining, apriori, hashtree

I am trying to figure out how to properly navigate a hash tree structure given a certain transaction.  I already have the answer to the question, but I'm not entirely sure how they arrived at it.

Here is a link to the [hash tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5QpJ.jpg)
[image: hash tree structure]

**Question:** Given a transaction that contains items {1,3,4,5,8}, which of the hash tree leaf nodes will be visited when finding the candidates of the transaction?

**Answer:** L1, L3, L5, L9, and L11

I understand that this is some form of Apriori, so my initial thought process is to look at the first node level {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, and {3, 6, 9} and if any of those 3 candidate itemsets contain at least 1 number in the transaction then proceed to the next node level, where you would check if at least 2 numbers were in the transaction, but that doesn't work at all.  If anyone could help explain how to navigate this type of hash tree using a transaction it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1,4,7` is not an itemset.

Every branch is a list of numbers modulo 3. If `x mod 3==1` you take the first branch, if `x mod 3==2` the second, and `x mod 3==0` the last branch.

Itemset `{145}`

- `1 mod 3 = 1`, thus the first branch in the top level
- `4 mod 3 = 1`, thus the first branch in the second level
- `5 mod 3 = 2`, thus the second branch in the third level (if it exists).

Comment: Ohhh okay, so I need to look at every possible 3-candidate combination in {1, 3, 4, 5, 8} and see which nodes are visited? So {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, etc.